# How to give single quotes within ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ExistingTeamMember", "alert('This \"Team Member\" already exists.');", true);
```

This is my ScriptManager  in codebehind page.

alert is

```
This "Team Member" already exists.
```

how i will make it to

```
     This 'Team Member' already exists.
```

I tried with

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ExistingTeamMember", "alert('This \'Team Member\' already exists.');", true);
```

It doesnot show the alert.

Comment: Try `'alert("This \'Team Member\' already exists.");',`

Comment: I tried with this i wont work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your attempt does not work is because the backslash is also an escape in .NET.

Currently .NET sees `\'` and expects it to be an escape sequence like a tab (`\t`) or a new line (`\n`). Since `\'` is not valid it is ignored and the string you end up with is not escaped.

You can make it work by escaping every `\` in your hard-coded string with another backslash (`\\`).

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ExistingTeamMember", "alert('This \\'Team Member\\' already exists.');", true);
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad to give it!